# Как узнать информацию о видео файле?

Tags: php, javascript

Доброго времени суток.
Нужно узнать информацию о видео файле (длину, формат, превью), есть ли такой скрипт на php 
или javascript?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: формат можно узнать через регулярки вытащив расширения.

Comment: Есть даже [расширение для php][1].

[1]:http://pyha.ru/forum/topic/1317.0

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [ExifTool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) , это Perl библиотека a не PHP, но думаю может помочь. Есть версия для прямого запуска на сервере из командной строки. Из плюсов бесплатность, кросс платформенность, поддержка ожесточающего количества разных форматов вплоть до PE заголовков .exe файлов. 
Кстати к этой штуковине кто-то уже приделал PHP wrapper. Так что скрипт который вам посоветовали просто детская игрушка по сравнению с этим монстром обработки метаданных.

[PHPExiftool](https://github.com/romainneutron/PHPExiftool)

Answer (score 0):

Tcm библиотека на php ffmpeg, поищи в гугле, только смотри внимательно под какую она версию php. Сам использую, жрет все форматы.